# Realm.io - How to use wildcard %LIKE% for a query

Tags: android, realm, wildcard, sql-like

I'm trying to do:

```
mRealm
         .where(Contact.class)
         .equalTo(Contact.NAME, text, Case.INSENSITIVE)
         .findAllSortedAsync(Contact.NAME, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Result: *Expected result not met.*

```
mRealm
         .where(Contact.class)
         .contains(Contact.NAME, text, Case.INSENSITIVE)
         .findAllSortedAsync(Contact.NAME, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Result: *Expected result not met.*

Expected result:

```
mRealm
         .where(Contact.class)
         .like(Contact.NAME, text, Case.INSENSITIVE)
         .findAllSortedAsync(Contact.NAME, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Answer (score 7):

NEW ANSWER:

Realm 2.3.0+:

> ```
> public RealmQuery<E> like(String fieldName,
>                       String value,
>                       Case casing)
> ```
>
> Condition that the value of field matches with the specified substring, with wildcards:
>
> - `'*'` matches `[0, n]` unicode chars
> - `'?'` matches a single unicode char.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `fieldName` - the field to compare.
> - `value` - the wildcard string.
> - `casing` - how to handle casing. Setting this to `Case.INSENSITIVE` only works for Latin-1 characters.
>
> Returns: the query object.
>
> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if one or more arguments do not match class or field type.

---

OLD ANSWER:

```
mRealm
     .where(Contact.class)
     .contains(Contact.NAME, text, Case.INSENSITIVE)
     .findAllSortedAsync(Contact.NAME, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

This should work, but you will receive a callback to an appended RealmChangeListener when the actual async query is completed.

A `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` does this automatically from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters.

Comment: Although you can run into issues with funky characters according to https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sorting-and-querying-on-string

Comment: Yeah, ".contains()" working fine on my app, But actually I need to search a fields which are in common "Contact.NAME" in the table. Eg ABBC, ABBA, CBBC --> %BB%

Comment: ... `contains(ContactFields.NAME, "BB");`?

Comment: In Wildcard's CONTAIN and LIKE operators return types are not equal. btw Thanks for help!

Comment: @charitharatnayake feel free to create a feature request at https://github.com/realm/realm-java

Comment: @charitharatnayake while I do not understand why `contains()` doesn't solve your problem, the [Realm-Core added WildCard support and Like method 2 days ago](https://github.com/realm/realm-core/commit/325966fe6595ba7fc3ff254bbb9a253719d3a201), so the binding ought to happen in Realm-Java eventually.

Answer (score 4):

```
mRealm
     .where(Contact.class)
     .like(Contact.NAME, text, Case.INSENSITIVE)
     .findAllSortedAsync(Contact.NAME, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: I'm using classpath **io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.1.1**, Which version you are using?

Comment: It's added in v2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code works for me .

```
Realm realm=Realm.getDefaultinstance();
RealmResults<Item> reaaa = realm.where(Item.class).like("name",query,Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
```